# Manual install of Deis on CoreOS

Tags: coreos, deis

I have installed CoreOS via the VMWare image file. Does anyone know how to install Deis.io? I have read through the documentation and most of it is how to install Deis on other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move forward setting up Deis by exporting `FLEETCTL_TUNNEL` and issuing a `make run` like the documentation suggests, but you'll be missing some of the provisioning steps that Deis performs as part of the [cloud-init script](https://github.com/deis/deis/blob/master/contrib/coreos/user-data). You'll likely run into trouble.

The recommended path is to install [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and issue a `vagrant up` in the project root to use the Deis project [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/deis/deis/blob/master/Vagrantfile). This sets up networking and executes the project cloud-init script.

Vagrant should detect that you have VMWare installed and not VirtualBox, and will provision appropriately.